# my htaccess rule goes to page and not id

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

i have a rental property website and i am migrating to a new site. i have problem with my rules from apache.

eg:
/FL/Miami/2/
/CA/San-Diego/41/

i want to be able to display dynamically a page based on the url

```
rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/$ index.php?state=$1&city=&mode=list
rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/$ index.php?state=$1&city=$2&mode=list
rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ index.php?state=$1&city=$2&id=$3
```

so i see all the list for each state or list for each state/city

now my problem is when i try to see page 2, i get the ID instead

is there a magic way to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what will work for you (put this in your .htaccess in your document root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1&city=&mode=list [NC,L,QSA]
rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1&city=$2&mode=list [NC,L,QSA]
rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1&city=$2&pagenum=$3&mode=page [NC,L,QSA]
rewriterule ^([a-z]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/?$ index.php?state=$1&city=$2&id=$3&mode=view [NC,L,QSA]
```

So:

`/california/san-diego/2` or `/california/san-diego/2/` will to go page 2

`/FL/Miami/2/home-house-test` or `/FL/Miami/2/home-house-test/` will to to the property page